# Is this grammar ambiguous? Does the production application matter on unambiguos grammar?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction

I'm playing with LR(1) parsers, I wrote a simple simple example, here is

```py
import time
def parse3(input):
    # e -> e '+' A | A
    # A -> '1' | '2'
    stack = []

    while True:
        try:
            print(stack)
            time.sleep(1)
            # try to reduce
            if stack[-1][0] == 'A':
                t = stack.pop()
                new = f"e{t}"
                stack.append(new)
                print(f"reduce e{t} <- {t}")
            elif stack[-1][0] in ('1', '2'):
                t = stack.pop()
                new = f"A{t}"
                stack.append(new)
                print(f"reduce A <- {t}")
            elif stack[-3][0] == 'e' and stack[-2] == '+' and stack[-1][0] == 'A':
                t3 = stack.pop()
                t2 = stack.pop()
                t1 = stack.pop()
                stack.append(f"e{t2}{t1}{t3}")
                print("reduce e <- e + A")
            else:
                raise RuntimeError(f"Parse error {stack}")
            continue
        except IndexError:
            # shift
            t = input.pop(0)
            stack.append(t)
            print(f"shift {t}")
            continue

        if len(stack) == 1 and not input:
            return stack[0]


print(parse3("1 + 2".split()))
```

I'm using prefix notation to create the parse tree, in some easy to visualize and printing friendly way. Here is the grammar

```
e -> e '+' A | A
A -> '1' | '2'
```

Here is the output of `1 + 2` parsing

```
[]
shift 1
['1']
reduce A <- 1
['A1']
reduce eA1 <- A1
['eA1']
shift +
['eA1', '+']
shift 2
['eA1', '+', '2']
reduce A <- 2
['eA1', '+', 'A2']
reduce eA2 <- A2
['eA1', '+', 'eA2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse2.py", line 233, in <module>
    print(parse3("1 + 2".split()))
  File "parse2.py", line 220, in parse3
    raise RuntimeError(f"Parse error {stack}")
RuntimeError: Parse error ['eA1', '+', 'eA2']
```

The problem that I have is that it reduces `reduce eA2 <- A2`. Then I get this in the stack `['eA1', '+', 'eA2']` and since there is no `e -> e + e` production rule, the parser exits with an error. If `e -> e '+' A` rule were applied before it would work, so this smells like a ambiguous grammar problem but I have no clue how to prove or solve that. Informally speaking if the grammar is unambiguous, the order or production rules application wouldn't matter. But if it is I have to resort to some kind of production rule priority, is this right?

Another question, are there programming languages grammars that are ambiguous? How compilers deal with that?

Comment: The grammar is not ambiguous but it does require an actual parsing table to work. Your parser is not based on the LR algorithm for generating a parsing table, so it chooses the wrong action.

Comment: Thanks rici, I thought that I only needed a parsing table to generate a parser from a grammar but it seems that is more than this, I'm reading about how to generate it.

Comment: You should check out the Dragon Book as they have some great introductory material on this.